# How to track all files a process opens in its lifetime

Tags: linux, filesystems, lsof

I am aware of using lsof for checking the files currently accessed by a process. Does there exist a way to see all files that an application opens in its lifetime?

Comment: [Continuously monitor files opened/accessed by a process](https://superuser.com/q/348738/241386)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using the **strace** command it migh be possible with something like :

```
strace -e trace=open program [arguments]
```

Comment: This will show all files that a process _tried_ to access. One might think that something like `strace -e trace=open program [arguments] | grep -v ' = -1 ENOENT'` could improve the situation, but it's not true either. The latter will fail to detect unfinished and then resumed calls to `open`.

Comment: Note that the signal you need might be `openat`.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure I have understood exactly what you want to do with this. But, have you considered strace ? It displays all system calls including files.

EDIT : Don't forget the -f option that allows you to follow forked processes.

Comment: Debugging which configuration files are read by an application